# Display Co-Ordinates

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

Cell `A1` has top left coord of box, `A2` has bottom right coord of box, how do I get `A3` to display all the coords of the box in csv format?

Ex:

```
Cell A1 = (24,20)
Cell A2 = (26,19)
```

How to get this?:

```
Cell A3 = (24,20),(25,20),(26,20),(24,19),(25,19),(26,19)
```

I am using Excel 2011

Comment: There isn't an actual box, just the cells that have the coordinates for the upper left and lower right corners.

Comment: Thanks for fixing up my post by the way, I'm not up to speed on the format here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? (*I hope I have understood your query correctly. If not then feel free to correct me*)

Paste this code in a module and then call the `=GetCord(A1,A2)` in cell `A3` as shown in the screenshot below.

```
Public Function GetCord(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As String
    Dim strTmp As String, strTmp1 As String, strTmp2 As String
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    strTmp1 = rng1.Value: strTmp2 = rng2.Value

    strTmp1 = Trim(Replace(strTmp1, "(", ""))
    strTmp1 = Trim(Replace(strTmp1, ")", ""))

    strTmp2 = Trim(Replace(strTmp2, "(", ""))
    strTmp2 = Trim(Replace(strTmp2, ")", ""))

    i = Val(Split(strTmp1, ",")(0))
    j = Val(Split(strTmp1, ",")(1))

    k = Val(Split(strTmp2, ",")(0))
    l = Val(Split(strTmp2, ",")(1))

    For b = j To l Step -1
        For a = i To k
            strTmp = strTmp & "(" & a & "," & b & "),"
        Next a
    Next b

    GetCord = Left(strTmp, Len(strTmp) - 1)
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Note**: The above function is assuming that the `y` Co-Ordinates are in decreasing order. To cater for all scenarios, you will have to include that check in the function.